# How to print the content of multiple text files with one click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text-files

Is there a way to print text from several text files with one click of a button? The code I am currently using is shown below.

```html
Dim FilePath = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Employee Record\" & TextBox1.Text))

            Dim FileNameRTO As String = Path.Combine(FilePath.FullName, TextBox2.Text + ".RTO")
            Dim ObjectReaderRTO As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileNameRTO)
            
            RichTextBox1.Text = ObjectReaderRTO.ReadToEnd
            ObjectReaderRTO.Close()
```

The current code searches a desktop directory “Employee Record” for the sub-directory whose title is specified in TextBox1.Text.

Then the code searches inside the sub-directory for the text file (file extension RTO) whose title is specified in TextBox2.Text.

Assuming there are more than one RTO text file in the sub-directory, how can I print all the text into one report with one click? Is this possible? I am using Visual Basic 2010. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a DirectoryInfo object for the folder. You can use the GetFiles method to get all the files with an extension of .RTO, and append them to the RichTextBox like this:

```
Dim FilePath As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Employee Record\" & TextBox1.Text))

RichTextBox1.Clear 'omit this line if you want to keep the current contents 
For Each FileRTO As FileInfo In FilePath.GetFiles("*.RTO", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(FileRTO.FullName))
Next
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me again. Thanks for your help, my dear friend.